# TextInput.finishAutofillContext not working for save credentials to google

Tags: android, ios, flutter, autofill

I am using Flutter version 2.8.1 with new migration as per this [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects) but I am not getting pop up while saving email and passwords.

TextInput.finishAutofillContext(shouldSave: true);

The above code, I am using on the press of submit button. It was working in flutter 2.5.1. Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow the doc here and remember to wrap your `Textfield` list with `AutoFillGroup`
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/autofillHints.html